# Python code for Round Robin Scheduling algorithm for CPU scheduling

Tags: python, cpu, round-robin

Need help to complete the code for Round Robin Scheduling algorithm for CPU scheduling.

Each process takes an equal share of CPU time which is equal to a time quantum of 2 units.
After being processed for 2 time quantums, if the process still requires more computation,
it is passed to a waiting queue.

The code should do the following:

- Report the time each process is completed
- Report wait times of each process in the queue

The #CODE indicates where the code is missing.
[image]

```
from collections import deque
time_quantum = 2

class Process:
  def __init__(self, name, arrival_time, required_time):
    self.name = name
    self.arrival_time = arrival_time
    self.required_time = required_time
    self.time_processed = 0
  def __repr__(self):
    return self.name

p0 = Process('P1', 0, 4)
p1 = Process('P2', 1, 3)
p2 = Process('P3', 2, 2)
p3 = Process('P4', 3, 1)
processes = [p0, p1, p2, p3]

end_times = {process.name:0 for process in processes}
wait_times = {process.name:0 for process in processes}

queue = deque()
running_proc = None # Tracks running process in the CPU
running_proc_time = 0 # Tracks the time running process spent in the CPU
for t in range(11):
#CODE 

print(end_times) # End times for each process
print(wait_times) # Wait times for each process in the queue
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? ("I need help" is not a question)

Comment: I need help with writing a code there indicated: #CODE. I understand the logic but I don't know how to apply it in Python.

Comment: Who is `t` and why `11` just before #CODE ?

Comment: @Demi-Lune. That's what the assignment states, to complete the given code. But I'm looking for any help, even if we replace t and 11.

Comment: You should read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions (i.e. make an attempt yourself).